# How can I link three different admin-users to an article?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core, code-first

In my CMS/CRM-system, the `Article`-class has three `AdminUser` properties, one for "created by", one for "edited by" and one for "published by":

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // some more properties ...
    public AdminUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public AdminUser EditedBy { get; set; }
    public AdminUser PublishedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The `AdminUser`-class:

```
public class AdminUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    // some more properties ...
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

(The `Member`-class just contains personal info like name, etc. In my system, not all members are admins, but all admins are members.)

This works fine when I don't have any reference to `Article` in the `AdminUser`-class. But if I want to be able to know anything about the articles an admin has created, edited or published, they have to be a part of the `AdminUser`-class:

```
public class AdminUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ... and the rest of the properties
    public List<Article> CreatedArticles { get; set; }
    public List<Article> EditedArticles { get; set; }
    public List<Article> PublishedArticles { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when trying to `add-migration`, I'm presented with the following error message:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'AdminUser.Articles' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I kind of understand what's going on, but I don't know how to "manually configure the relationship".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign relationship between `AdminUser` and `Article` . You can use [Has/With pattern](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haswith-pattern) to configure relationships with the Fluent API . In your dbcontext ,adding relationship  :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AdminUser>()
      .HasMany(c => c.EditedArticles)
      .WithOne(e => e.EditedBy);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AdminUser>()
    .HasMany(c => c.CreatedArticles)
    .WithOne(e => e.CreatedBy);


    modelBuilder.Entity<AdminUser>()
    .HasMany(c => c.PublishedArticles)
    .WithOne(e => e.PublishedBy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your `Article` Fluent API configuration as follows:

```
public class ArticleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Article>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Article> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(a => a.CreatedBy).WithMany(au => au.CreatedArticles);
        builder.HasOne(a => a.EditedBy).WithMany(au => au.EditedArticles);
        builder.HasOne(a => a.PublishedBy).WithMany(au => au.PublishedArticles);
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` of the `DbConetxt` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ArticleConfiguration());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add a table in your sql called **author** and give it 
**( id , author.Id, author_job, article_id)** 
then in the job you can decide what that author did to the article

Comment: Although I have accepted Nan Yu's answer, I may very well go with your suggestion. That way I will get a full changelog for each article, not just the last edit.

Comment: Glad you like it.